# How to Load Partial Views with Jquery UI Tab by passing parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a parent page (**DistributionReview.aspx**) that has a **Deposit Date** to select using DatePicker.

Just below I have **two tabs**(**DistributionByType** and **DistibutionByStatus**) that I want to load PartialViews. ***Here the parameter to the PartialView is DepositDate***.

And I have a custom ViewModel called **DistributionReviewModel** that the parent page is implementing.

I am coming across articles that are directly loading static partial views(Ex: 
http://www.kevgriffin.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/23/using-jquery-tabs-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views-for-ajax-goodness/
 ). But I am looking for any code sample/articles by passing parameter?

Appreciate if anyone can share code samples to pass parameters and **load the partialview both when the TabSelection is changed and and DepositDate is changed**.

Thanks for your time.

**Html Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    //tab
    $("#divDistributionReview").tabs();

    $("#fileDepositDate").datepicker(); //DateTime Picker
    var depositDate = $("#fileDepositDate").val();

});
```

```
<div id="container" >

<% using (Html.BeginForm("frmDistributionReview", "DistibutionReview"))
{ %>

    <div> Select a Date: &nbsp;     <input type="text" id="fileDepositDate" name="datepicker"  value='<%= ViewData["FileDepositDate"] %>' /></div>     
    <div id="divDistributionReview">             
    <ul>                 
    <li><a href="/DistributionReview/DistributionByType">Distribution Type</a></li>                 
    <li><a href="/DistributionReview/DistributionByStatus">Status</a></li>             
    </ul>     
    </div> 
        <%} %>
</div>
```

**C# Code:**

```
public ActionResult DistributionReview()
    {
        ViewData["FileDepositDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var view = View(ApplicationConstants.DistributionReviewViewName, new MegaLockbox.Web.ViewModels.DistributionByTypeViewModel(securityManager, distributionReviewDataAdapter, Convert.ToDateTime(ViewData["FileDepositDate"])));
        return view;
    }


    public ActionResult DistributionByType(string id)
    {
        DateTime depositDate;
        var view = new PartialViewResult();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(id , out depositDate))
        {
            view = PartialView(ApplicationConstants.DistributionByTypeViewName, new MegaLockbox.Web.ViewModels.DistributionByTypeViewModel(securityManager, distributionReviewDataAdapter, depositDate));
        }
        return view;
    }

    public ActionResult DistributionByStatus(string id)
    {
        DateTime depositDate;
        var view = new PartialViewResult();
        if(DateTime.TryParse(id, out depositDate) )
        {
            view = PartialView(ApplicationConstants.DistributionByStatusViewName, new MegaLockbox.Web.ViewModels.DistributionByTypeViewModel(securityManager, distributionReviewDataAdapter, depositDate));
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You can have one method(action) in controller  and pass two parameters one for data and one for type('status' or 'type')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you have nice guide how to do this:

http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/jquery-ui-tabs-and-aspnet-mvc/

if you have any questions.. let us know:)

PS you can download the example, and play with it

Answer (score 2):

Html for tab headers

```
  <li><a onclick="LoadTabData('type')" href="/DistributionReview/DistributionByType">Distribution   Type</a></li>                 
        <li><a onclick="LoadTabData('status')"  href="/DistributionReview/DistributionByStatus">Status</a></li>
```

Jquery function

```
function LoadTabData(type){

if(type='type')

       $.post("YourController/DistributionByType", { id:  $("#fileDepositDate").val()},
            function(data) {
               $(#"yourByTypeTabDiv").html(data);
       });

}else{
  $.post("YourController/DistributionByStatus", { id:  $("#fileDepositDate").val()},
            function(data) {
                $(#"yourByStatusTabDiv").html(data);
       });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this will work.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
 <div id="tab-1">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewForTab1", Model)
 </div>
 <div id="tab-2">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewForTab2", Model)
 </div>
 <div id="tab-3">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewForTab3", Model)
 </div>
</div>
```